# How to store an array of enum in hibernate

Tags: java, arrays, hibernate, jpa, enums

I am trying to persist an array of enum, using Hibernate. It is important to note that if it is possible, I would rather not use a collection.  The answers that I have found online so far are for storing collections, not arrays.

I am getting a runtime error complaining about missing an @OrderColumn or @IndexColumn.  I don't want the array ordered alphabetically.  I want it to be returned in the same order.

The enum's are literally as simple as you could ask for, but the Enum.name() are not in alphabetical order, so there doesn't seem to be a natural "Order" column.

```
@Embeddable
public enum SudokuPossibleValueState {
                                  UNDEFINED, UNKNOWN, IMPOSSIBLE, POSSIBLE, COMMITTED, AS_PUBLISHED;

    public String toString() {
        return name().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

By definition, I am using the actual position in the array to indicate the number that I am considering, and the enum defines the state of the evaluation for that number.  For example, a typical array might be ...

```
[0] = UNDEFINED, 
[1] = UNDEFINED, 
[2] = POSSIBLE, 
[3] = POSSIBLE, 
[4] = UNKNOWN, 
[5] = UNKNOWN, 
[6] = UNKNOWN, 
[7] = IMPOSSIBLE, 
[8] = IMPOSSIBLE,
[9] = IMPOSSIBLE.
```

But the challenge I am encountering is that all of the examples that I can find online, and the Hibernate documentation, only seem to address the situation where you are using a Java collection; which is not what I am trying to do.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SudokuPossibleValues")
public class SudokuPossibleValuesModel {   
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_VALUES_PLUS_ONE = 10;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long possibleValuesID;

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SudokuPossibleValueState stateValues[] = new SudokuPossibleValueState[NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_VALUES_PLUS_ONE];
    ...
}
```

Comment: FWIW An "enum" is not `@Embeddable`. It is a basic type.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful; removing it at least changed the errors that I was getting.  Eventually, I just gave in, and did the hack described below.

Comment: You can use a UserType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an answer, but please tell me there is a better way within either JPA or Hibernate to do this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POSSIBLE_VALUES")
public class PossibleValues {

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   private static final long serialVersionUID                   = -1L;    
   public static final int   NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_VALUES_PLUS_ONE = 10;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "possibleValuesID")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "possibleValuesID", strategy = "increment")
   @Column(name = "POSSIBLE_VALUES_ID")
   private Long possibleValuesID;

   @Transient
   private SudokuPossibleValueState[] values = new SudokuPossibleValueState[NUMBER_OF_POSSIBLE_VALUES_PLUS_ONE];
   // Ugly, disgusting hack, to deal with getting an Enumerated collection in/out of JPA/Hibernate
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState zero  = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState one   = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState two   = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState three = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState four  = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState five  = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState six   = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState seven = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState eight = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private SudokuPossibleValueState nine  = SudokuPossibleValueState.UNDEFINED;

   // Ugly, disgusting hack, to deal with getting an Enumerated array in/out of JPA/Hibernate
   public PossibleValues() {
      values[0] = zero;
      values[1] = one;
      values[2] = two;
      values[3] = three;
      values[4] = four;
      values[5] = five;
      values[6] = six;
      values[7] = seven;
      values[8] = eight;
      values[9] = nine;
   }

   // Ugly, disgusting hack, to deal with getting an Enumerated array in/out of JPA/Hibernate
   protected void setPossibleValue(short possibleValue, SudokuPossibleValueState state) {
      switch (possibleValue) {
         case 0: values[possibleValue] = zero = state; break;
         case 1: values[possibleValue] = one = state; break;
         case 2: values[possibleValue] = two = state; break;
         case 3: values[possibleValue] = three = state; break;
         case 4: values[possibleValue] = four = state; break;
         case 5: values[possibleValue] = five = state; break;
         case 6: values[possibleValue] = six = state; break;
         case 7: values[possibleValue] = seven = state; break;
         case 8: values[possibleValue] = eight = state; break;
         case 9: values[possibleValue] = nine = state; break;
         default: throw new RuntimeException("Possible Value [" + possibleValue + "] is illegal");
      }
   }

   // Ugly, disgusting hack, to deal with getting an Enumerated array in/out of JPA/Hibernate
   @PostLoad
   protected void syncState() {
      values[0] = zero;
      values[1] = one;
      values[2] = two;
      values[3] = three;
      values[4] = four;
      values[5] = five;
      values[6] = six;
      values[7] = seven;
      values[8] = eight;
      values[9] = nine;
   }

   public Long getPossibleValuesID() {
      return possibleValuesID;
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   private void setPossibleValuesID(Long possibleValuesID) {
      this.possibleValuesID = possibleValuesID;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Late with the answer, but I've done the same and created this class:

```
public abstract class EEnumArrayAttributeConverter<E extends Enum<E>> implements AttributeConverter<E[], String> {

    private static final String DIVIDER = "|";

    private final Class<E> classEnum;
    protected EEnumArrayAttributeConverter(final Class<E> classEnum) {
        this.classEnum = classEnum; 
    }
    
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final E[] values) {
        String retVal = "";
        if (null != values) {
            for (final E value : values) {
                if (!retVal.isEmpty()) {
                    retVal += DIVIDER;
                }
                retVal += value.name();
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    protected abstract E[] create(final int size);
    
    @Override
    public E[] convertToEntityAttribute(final String str) {
        if ((null == str) || str.isEmpty()) {
            return create(0);
        }
        else {
            final String[] parts = str.split("\\"+ DIVIDER);
            final E[] retVal = create(parts.length);
            for (int x = 0; x < parts.length; x++) {
                retVal[x] = E.valueOf(classEnum, parts[x]);
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would have the converter implementation as:

```
public class ESudokuPossibleValueStateArrayAttributeConverter extends EEnumArrayAttributeConverter<SudokuPossibleValueState> {
    public ESudokuPossibleValueStateArrayAttributeConverter() {
        super(SudokuPossibleValueState.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected SudokuPossibleValueState[] create(int size) {
        return new SudokuPossibleValueState[size];
    }
}
```

And then in your class:

```
@Convert(converter = ESudokuPossibleValueStateArrayAttributeConverter.class)
private SudokuPossibleValueState stateValues[];
```